# How can I uses SSMS to create an Azure Database that is General Purpose 2GB

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have tried several combinations with no luck. In SSMS, going to Tasks | Deploy Database to Microsoft Azure SQL Database, what do I set in:

[image]

and

[image]

to end up with

[image]